# prox sensor with NPN open collector output or a dry contact

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, npn, input, open-collector

I am totally new in this field. I want to use a 5 V / TTL signal from a National Instrument to switch on/off a Red lion PXU series temperature controller. But this controller required a dry contact input or a prox sensor with NPN open collector.
What does it mean?

How will the circuit look like?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It means you need to pull down the input to instrument ground with a transistor or switch.

Read the specifications to determine what voltage it pulls up to, or just add an NPN transistor and base resistor (eg. 2N4401/4.7K) to your logic circuit. Grounds must be common.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpiLh7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can probably use a transistor or MOSFET-output optoisolator rather than a transistor if you need isolation, but you may need a driver for the optoisolator LED.